# JQuery Scroll DRY

Tags: jquery, scroll, dry

I have 4 divs that I want to have a scroll action applied to.

The code works if I repeat it for each div but I want to just have one block of code to handle the event.

The code that works is this -

```
$('nav').on('click', function(){ 
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#about').offset().top}, 1000)
});
```

The code that I would like to now use is this -

```
var navText = $('.nav-text').on('click', function() {
            var txt = $(this).attr('id');
            var id = '#' + txt;
            console.log(id);
        });
$('nav').on('click', function(){ 
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(navText).offset().top}, 1000)
});
```

When the above code is applied and the link is clicked the page only goes down a few pixels.

Thank you for your help.

Cheers,

Ryan

Comment: What is `.nav-text` and `nav` here, and why would `navText` ever be anything other than the same jQuery collection every time you click? You should probably post an example of the HTML and how this is supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

- Your variable `navText` contains the click-handler and not the `id` you are looking for
- From the structure of your code I assume you are using duplicate IDs which can lead to issues

Without knowing your mark-up this code could work for you:

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-id="id1" class="nav-text"></a>
```

JS

```
$('.nav-text').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var dataId = $(this).data('id');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + dataId).offset().top
  }, 1000)
});
```